# Words in wordlist appear with character spaces in Rapidminer.

Tags: rapidminer, word-list

I created wordlists from a single text file & it worked fine. Steps:-

Process Operators: Retrieve data > Nominal to Text > Process Documents from Data > Sub-process Operators: Tokenize > Transform Cases > Filter Tokens (by length) >Filter Stopwords (English) > Stem (Snowball)
Vector Creation is TF-IDF & Prune method absolute, Prune below 1 & Prune above 5 (since its a file with very few rows)
Sample words from resulting wordlist:
analyst
cloud
clear
But when I did the same from a corpus of text files the resulting wordlist had character spacing within each word. Steps:
Process Documents from Files (select the corpus Directory) with vector creation as TF-IDF & Prune method as none
Sub-process: Tokenize > Filter Stopwords (English) > Filter Tokens (by Length) > Stem (Snowball) > Transform Cases (to lowercase)
I set a breakpoint at Tokenize & noticed that the character spacing within words appeared at this stage itself. The source text files did not have such issue with the data. 
Sample words from the resulting WordList:

## a g i l e

e m p o w e r
b i g d a t a

Could someone please help resolve this? Are there any other parameters to set or any other operators to be used in the process to resolve this issue and to create a more meaningful and concentrated wordlist?
Thanks, Geeta

Comment: This is very hard to answer without the data. What exactly is the format of the data in the second case?

Comment: In the 2nd case I have some tab delimited text files in a corpus folder. Hence I was using "Process Documents from Files" operator.

Whereas in the 1st case I had uploaded a tab delimited text file to the data folder under the Local Repository and hence used the "Retrieve" operator to get the data from this file. The data was getting retrieved as polynominal data. Hence, applied the "nominal to text" operator here.

Comment: In the 2nd case I have some tab delimited text files in a corpus folder. Hence I was using "Process Documents from Files" operator. Assuming that this text data was retrieved in a polynominal format I tried to apply the "nominal to Text" operator but its not working. 

Whereas in the 1st case I had uploaded a tab delimited text file to the data folder under the Local Repository and hence used the "Retrieve" operator to get the data from this file. The data got retrieved as polynominal data. Hence, applied the "nominal to text" operator here. I explained the steps taken in my earlier post

Comment: What are the parameters of the `Tokenize` operator?

Comment: Tokenize parameters have the default values - Mode is "linguistic tokens" and Language  is " English" for the 2nd case where I am reading multiple files from a corpus folder.

Comment: When I changed the values for the Mode parameter it does not tokenize the documents properly.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, no progress can be made.

Comment: Here is the link to the XML code for the process I had created to generate wordlist from multiple tab delimited text files.
https://netappinc.sharefile.com/d-s7859ab85d204f78a

Comment: This is not a reproducible example because too much effort is required. You should also edit the original question so that it stands by itself and can be useful to others in the future. I can tell you however that `Linguistic Tokens` is probably wrong - you should use `Non letters`. You are also using a word list as input to the `Process Documents from Files` operator. Remove that and see what happens.